# Laravel login problem with 2 table(admin_users and users)

Tags: laravel

I am implementing two login processes in Laravel, one for the API and another for the web. I want to use the 'users' table for the API and the 'admin_users' table for the admin panel on the web. For this, I made some configurations in the config file, and currently, I am not facing any issues on the API side. However, I am encountering problems on the web side. I'm sharing my existing code with you. When I try to log in on the web, I see the success log, but I don't get redirected; instead, the page refreshes. What should I do?

auth.php(config)

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin_users' => [
        'guard' => 'admin_users',
        'passwords' => 'admin_users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin_users' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admin_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\AdminUser::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admin_users' => [
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

auth.php(routes)

```
Route::get('/', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'index'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('login');

Route::post('/', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest');
```

kernel.php

```
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next,)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin_users')->check()) {
            // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::guard('admin_users')->attempt($credentials)) {
            Log::info('Admin login success for email: '.$request->email);
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }else{
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('Wrong email or password'),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

```
public const HOME = 'admin/dashboard';
```

If I activate the 'return' part in my middleware file, I receive an error on the screen indicating that I am redirecting too much. That's why I left it as a comment for now. I have been struggling with this for a long time, but I haven't been able to succeed.

Comment: If I change the 'guard' and 'passwords' values in the 'defaults' section of the config to 'admin_users,' I don't encounter any issues on the web side, but I face problems on the API side.

Comment: have you set middleware for admin/dashboard? check your route middleware or the controller construct

Comment: Yes, I have configured the 'RedirectIfAuthenticated.php' file, which is in my middleware folder. However, I'm not doing anything here; I'm just logging. The issue is that it's not working in my main controller function.

Comment: please check if your login method is available to guest only and your dashboard index is guarded by auth middleware; redirection occurs somewhere there I suppose

Comment: when I remove the middleware, the issue persists. In other words, if I don't use the guest middleware in the route section, there is no change, and the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, and I will explain it in detail.I have examined the documentation here and reached some conclusions.[Laravel Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users%5D)

Then, I realized that the login process was actually successful, but there was no middleware structure between the route I directed in the 'route' folder. It was logging in every time, and I made this change:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin_users'], function () {.
```

In fact, it was going to the page I directed each time, but since the middleware didn't recognize this page correctly, it was redirecting back to the login page. It turned out to be something that looked like a refresh, and I solved the issue.